# Update Docusign Sender Name and set up it to No reply

Tags: docusignapi

I created a Envelope and EnvelopeFromTemplates using the Docusign API in Salesforce. We used a DocuSign user in Salesforce, and we have different role in Salesforce. The program is working, but we need to update the email's name and set up this email as no-reply. This email is sign email. For example: DocuSign User A is set in Salesforce. Salesforce User A clicks a Sign button, and an email from Docusign User A is sent to the client. But the client will see Docusign User A. We want to change the email's name to Salesforce User A and this email is no reply. How can we do that?

Comment: add your code snippet for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

You can override the reply email address and name.  [Here is the documentation](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Add%20Email%20Setting%20Overrides%20to%20an%20Envelope.htm).

```
<ns:EnvelopeInformation>
    ...
    <ns:EmailSettings>
        <ns:ReplyEmailAddressOverride>johnqsigner@fakeemail.com</ns:ReplyEmailAddressOverride>
        <ns:ReplyEmailNameOverride>John Q Signer</ns:ReplyEmailNameOverride>
    </ns:EmailSettings>
    ...
 </ns:EnvelopeInformation>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will check this document and let you know if there is any questions. Thanks

Comment: Hi @reinkesm, We used SOAP API in our code, however, the document is Rest API. Could you please give me a example for the SOAP API? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now i can set ReplyEmail Address and ReplyEmailName. But i also want to set Docusign Sender Name. Do you know this?

Comment: The sender name is pulled from the "User Name" of the sending user account.  You would go into the console under Preferences -> Users to find those and change if necessary.

Please mark the answer as accepted if it did the trick.  :)