# How can I change the DocuSign sender name?

Tags: docusignapi

We developed a document management app. Users in our app need to sign document. Since they may not have DocuSign account, we use our DocuSign account to send signature request for them.

For example, A and B are both users in my app. A send document signature request to B, My app create envelop with B as an embedded recipient, then, I get the signing URL and send it to B through my app. After that B open my app and sign the document by embedded view.

Because we use my developer account to send envelop, B always get envelop shows “xxx (My account) request your signature”, but how can I make envelop shows “A (A’s) email requests your signature”?

By the way, we send envelop via Restful API.

I have got this [ [Update Docusign Sender Name and set up it to No reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036663/update-docusign-sender-name-and-set-up-it-to-no-reply) ], but our app has not create individual DocuSign account for our user.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to create a new user in your account which will represent a generic user/sender. For example, it sounds like today it says 'Xiaobing requests your signature' since the envelopes are being created using your user. Instead, you will want to create a new generic user (i.e: "Document Management App requests your signature"). Once you have this created, you can either create envelopes using the credentials (username/pwd) of this generic user, OR you can send the envelopes on behalf of this user: https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#SOBO/Send%20On%20Behalf%20Of%20Functionality%20in%20the%20DocuSign%20REST%20API.htm?Highlight=on%20behalf%20of

There is no way to simply override the sender name in real time - the sender name is going gt match the user information of who created this envelope.

On a per envelope level, you can indeed override the 'reply-to' email address for remote signing scenarios.

Comment: Many thanks. SOBO only works for users within the same account? Could I send signature request for users in our app with their our DocuSign account, oauth or other method?

Comment: Yes this could be done using OAuth2 - https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#OAuth2/OAuth2 Authentication Support in DocuSign REST API.htm%3FTocPath%3DOAuth2%2520Authentication%2520Support%2520in%2520DocuSign%2520REST%2520API%7C_____0

Answer (score 0):

Just change the name of your user account in your profile.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your docusign Display sender name from docusign Account setting check the below link

[change Dosudign sender Display name](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=pik1583277475390&topicId=dpc1583277401793.html&_LANG=enus)

Comment: Or you can try the below link

https://dynamo-docs.documill.com/integrations-and-additional-modules/integration-implementation-guide/change-sender-information-in-notification-emails.html#:~:text=The%20account's%20full%20name%20and%20log%2Din%20email%20address%20are%20used,-By%20default%2C%20or&text=This%20information%20can%20be%20seen,and%20your%20account%20email%20address.